# Scientific journal table of variable mean per year with S. D

Tags: r, summary

I have claims level data for health care consumption. I would like to create a journal quality table (exportable into Word) similar to the one below. That is I would like to calculate the price (and S.D. in parenthesis) of all DRGs per year.

Is there a package that will do this for me?

[image]

Comment: you might consider  this package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expss/index.html

Comment: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/save_kable_and_as_image.html may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample `rmarkdown` document that renders a table to Word, PDF, or html. The code uses `kable` and `kableExtra` for [html](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html) and [PDF](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) tables, and [`flextable`](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/overview.html) for Word tables. The Vignettes for these packages (see the links above) provide details on how to customize table formatting.

Some other resources for generating tables in R are [here](https://gist.github.com/davebraze/f73cc377fdee3b0b0373f0abc5a9725b) and [here](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/design-principles.html).

````
---
title: "My Report"
output:
  word_document: default
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r}
# Fake data
set.seed(2)
d = data.frame(years = sample(2014:2016, 100, replace=TRUE),
               drg = sample(paste0("DRG",1:4), 100, replace=TRUE), 
               value=runif(100, 0, 10))

# Set up table data
tab = d %>% 
  group_by(drg, years) %>% 
  summarise(mean = sprintf("%1.2f", mean(value)),
            sd = sprintf("(%1.2f)", sd(value))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(mean, sd), names_to="var") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=years, values_from=value) %>% 
  select(-var)

names(tab)[1] = " "
```

```{r}
# Print latex, html or Word table, depending on output type
out = ifelse(is_html_output(), "html", 
             ifelse(is_latex_output(), "latex", "word"))

if(out != "word") {
  kable(tab, format=out, booktabs=ifelse(out=="latex", TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
    kable_styling() %>% 
    collapse_rows(columns=1)
} else (
  tab %>% 
    flextable() %>% 
    merge_v(j=" ") %>% 
    theme_vanilla() %>% 
    hline(i = seq(1,nrow(tab),2), j=2:4, border=fp_border(color="white")) %>% 
    height(height=0.25, part="body")
)
```
````

Here's what the Word output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @eipi10. This is exactly what I am looking for. Two comments. I get an error msg when trying to knit it into word. "Error in knit_print.flextable(x, ...) : pandoc version >= 2.0 required for flextable rendering in docx " Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: I solved the other problem, so only one comment. :-)

Comment: Based on the information in the error message, it looks like you'll need to [install the latest version of Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/installing.html). Pandoc is not an R package, but a separate software application that "under the hood" is actually doing the conversion between document formats.